# Artículo definido - día de la semana

Tags: artículos, tiempo

Supongamos que tengo una pregunta acerca del día de la semana:

> — ¿Cuándo es el concierto, __ sábado o __ domingo?
>   — __ sábado.

Yo no sé si completamos con artículo o no. Yo sé que para un día específico sí completamos. Pero no sé si es el caso aquí. Yo utilizo el libro *Gramática de uso del español*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El artículo definido sólo puede omitirse cuando se habla en forma indeterminada de los días, en cuyo caso podría utilizarse el artículo indefinido o ningún artículo:

- ¿Qué día preferís que sea el concierto: **sábado** o **domingo**? (un sábado o un domingo cualquiera)
- ¿Qué día preferís que sea el concierto: **un sábado** o **un domingo**? (un sábado o un domingo cualquiera)

Cuando se habla de un día en particular, se usa "el":

- ¿Cuándo es el concierto: **el sábado** o **el domingo**? (el sábado o el domingo que viene)

Answer (score 2):

En castellano se usa el artículo  masculino **el** para los días de la semana, con lo que tu ejemplo se leería:

> *¿Cuándo es el concierto: **el sábado** o **el domingo**?*

***El* sábado**.

En el diccionario RAE, (ver la [fuente](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ESraxkH)) se consigna ese  uso

> 3. art. deter. m. y f. El más próximo al que habla. U. ante ciertos sustantivos o sintagmas nominales que designan unidades del calendario. Se incorporó en el mes de septiembre. *El viernes empieza las vacaciones*