# The 2nd 'el' in 'El partido no es el lunes.'

Tags: artículos

The translation of 'The game is not on Monday.' is

'El partido no es el lunes.'

I'm curious why there is 'el' before lunes.

Is this because it refers to a specific Monday?

If it is true, there should be no 'el' or 'los' in the Spanish translation of the sentence 'Most NFL games are held on Sundays.' because it is not about a specific day or days but about a general principle.

However, Google translate suggested 'La mayoría de los juegos de la NFL se llevan a cabo los domingos.'

Why is there 'los' before domingos?

Comment: Does this Q&A help https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31861/art%C3%ADculo-definido-d%C3%ADa-de-la-semana